# Store element into an array from other function

Tags: c

I am trying to implement the function `fillarray` to store values in array. But the elements are not being stored in the array.

**CODE:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fillarray(int array[],int num)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nenter your %d numbers",num);
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
}

void printarray(int array[],int num)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n\nyour array is : \n");
    for(i=0;i<num;i++);
    {
        printf("%d",array[i]);  
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("\nhow many numbers??\n");
    int num,i;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    int array[num];
    fillarray(array,num);
    printarray(array,num);
}
```

Comment: How do you know? What does the debugger say? Why don't you check the result of `scanf`? What does it return? What is the input? Read [ask] and follow the advice!

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. It will pay off in the future as well.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know that they're not being stored in the array - Is it because they're not being printed?

That's because there's a typo in your `printarray` function - remove the semicolon at the end of the line:

```
for(i=0;i<num;i++);
```

What's happening at the moment is that the loop does nothing. When it finishes, `i` will contain the value `num`. It will then attempt to print that index of array which invokes [Undefined Behavior](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Oh, and do check `scanf`'s results as [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4774918/olaf) [said in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746673/store-element-into-an-array-from-other-function#comment72610342_42746673).